# How can I gather the error stack when the app crashed from JNI?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

As the title, I want to gather the error stack when the app crashed from JNI. I can't figure out how to do it after a few days. Could you give me any suggestions?

Comment: It's possible, but it's not for the weak of heart; better find and integrate a ready made crash reporting framework.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941314/calling-exception-printstacktrace-from-jni